# Solving $y''-2xy'+xy = 0$ using power series

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

How to find a power series solution for $y''-2xy'+xy=0$

I can get to the point where I find that

$y''-2xy'+xy$

$\displaystyle= 2a_2 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-2na_n+a_{n-1}\big)x^n = 0$

and from there

$a_2=0\;$ and $\;a_{n+2}=\dfrac{2na_n-a_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)}$

But I don't really know how to proceed or find a general term for a,
because there is both $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ in the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

Was there an initial condition given?  Since you are dealing with a second order differential equation there will be two unknown coefficients in the explicit solution to the equation, when we solve it with power series this corresponds to having two unknown coefficients of the series $a_0,a_1$, and the rest of them are based on those.  Start by plugging in n=1 to your recurrence relation:

$a_3 = \frac{(2a_1-a_0)}{(3)(2)}=\frac{a_1}{3}-\frac{a_0}{6}$

Now n=2

$a_4 = \frac{4a_2-a_1}{(4)(3)}=\frac{-a_1}{12}$

Now n=3

$a_5 = \frac{10a_4-a_3}{(5)(4)}= \frac{a_4}{2}-\frac{a_3}{20}$

But, now we can substitute in the previous relations to rewrite this one in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$ also:

$a_5 = \frac{-a_1}{24} - \frac{a_1}{60}+\frac{a_0}{120} = \frac{-7a_1+a_0}{12
0}$

Comment: The general term is being asked for here.

Comment: There was no initial conditions, so the answer should have 2 unknown coefficients.

Comment: Were you asked to actually find an explicit formula for $a_n$, because generally that is difficult to do unless your differential equation is "very nice"

Comment: Yes I was asked to find an explicit formula, but I'm also starting to think that there might have been a typo in the equation from the professor, because this seems to be a really hard exercise.